# setting a changeable Variable into a menubar entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am currently working on my Graphical User Interface for my program and I want to create an Entry widget in a menubar (in my case in the `menubaroptions` method) that shows an *IntVar* which is set to a certain number (in my case: 9) but is changeable by the user. In my Code i tried it with `self.entrystring.get()` but got the "`self is not defined`" error.

This is part of my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter.constants import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from struct import unpack
from codecs import decode


class Graphicaluserinterface(tkinter.Frame):

    @classmethod
    def main(cls):
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        root.title('Program')
        root.minsize(560, 105)
        gui = cls(root)
        gui.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
        root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root['menu'] = gui.menubar
        root.mainloop()

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.inputliste = []
        self.check1 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.check2 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.check3 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.check5 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.inputfilenamelist = []
        self.fileopenname = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.fileopenname1 = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.filesavename  =tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entrystring = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.taktzykluszeit = tkinter.DoubleVar()
        self.taktunterschiedboolean = tkinter.BooleanVar()
        self.fileopeningcounter = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.fileopeningcounter.set(0)
        self.menubar = tkinter.Menu(self)
        self.file_menu = tkinter.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=FALSE)
        self.help_menu = tkinter.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=FALSE)
        self.program_start = tkinter.Button(self, text='Start Program')
        self.check_button1 = tkinter.Checkbutton(
        self, text="Drehzahl und Drehmoment", variable=self.check1,
        onvalue=1, offvalue=0
    )
        self.check_button2 = tkinter.Checkbutton(
        self, text="Analogvoltsensoren", variable=self.check2,
        onvalue=1, offvalue=0
    )
        self.check_button3 = tkinter.Checkbutton(
        self, text="Analogamperesensoren", variable=self.check3,
        onvalue=1, offvalue=0
    )
        self.check_button4 = tkinter.Checkbutton(
        self, text="Thermoelemente", variable=self.check4,
        onvalue=1, offvalue=0
    )
        self.check_button5 = tkinter.Checkbutton(
        self, text="Pt-100-Elemente", variable=self.check5,
        onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        self.input_path_display = tkinter.Label(
        self, textvariable=self.fileopenname1, bg='white', width=60
    )
        self.output_path_display = tkinter.Label(
        self, textvariable=self.filesavename, bg="white", width=60
    )
        self.input_path_display_label = tkinter.Label(self, text="Inputfile")
        self.output_path_display_label = tkinter.Label(self, text="Outputfile")
        self.create_widgets()
        self.entrystring.set(9)
        self.taktzykluszeit.set(0.0)
        self.taktunterschiedboolean.set(False)

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.file_menu)
        self.file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=lambda:[self.inputfilenamelist.clear(),self.fileopening()])
        self.file_menu.add_command(label="Save As")
        self.file_menu.add_command(label="Options",command=self.menubaroptions)
        self.file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.master.destroy)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Extras", menu=self.help_menu)
        self.help_menu.add_command(label="Help")
        self.help_menu.add_command(label="Credits")
        pad = dict(padx=5, pady=5)
        self.check_button1.grid(row=0, column=0, **pad)
        self.check_button2.grid(row=1, column=0, **pad)
        self.check_button3.grid(row=2, column=0, **pad)
        self.check_button4.grid(row=3, column=0, **pad)
        self.check_button5.grid(row=4, column=0, **pad)
        self.input_path_display_label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=EW, **pad)
        self.input_path_display.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=NSEW, **pad)
        self.output_path_display_label.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=EW, **pad)
        self.output_path_display.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=NSEW, **pad)
        self.program_start.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=EW, **pad)
        #self.program_start["command"]=lambda:[self.fileselectwarning(),self.writealldatafile(),self.writeselecteddata(),
        #                                     self.inputliste.clear(),self.fileopeningcounter.set(0),
        #                                     self.inputfilenamelist.clear()]
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

    def menubaroptions(root):
        optionswindow = tkinter.Toplevel(root)
        optionswindow.title("Options")
        optionswindow.minsize(300,150)
        trennzeichenlabel = tkinter.Label(optionswindow,text="Length of Separator in Byte:").pack()
        trennzeichenentry = tkinter.Entry(optionswindow,textvariable=self.entrystring.get(),width=30,justify="center").pack()
        taktzykluszeitlabel = tkinter.Label(optionswindow,text="Measurementtime for all \n Temperature-Sensors in sec").pack()
        taktzykluszeitentry = tkinter.Entry(optionswindow,textvariable=self.taktzykluszeit.get(),width=30,justify="center").pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Graphicaluserinterface.main()
```

i know there is a line which should be indented but it wasn´t working here, i have it indented in my code though.

Comment: There is no `self` in `menubaroptions()`, because you named its first parameter `root` instead.  Note that calling `.get()` on a Tkinter var is guaranteed to give you a value that is unsuitable for use with the `textvariable=` option of a widget; pass the var itself!

Comment: sorry for answering this late, i wasn´t able to work on this for the last couple of days. Can u elaborate on how to pass the Var itself?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues:

In the function `menubaroptions()` you assign the textvariable to the `IntVar.get()` method when you should assign to the object:

```
trennzeichenentry = tkinter.Entry( ... textvariable=self.entrystring.get(), ...).pack()
```

should be:

```
trennzeichenentry = tkinter.Entry( ... textvariable=self.entrystring, ...).pack()
```

Then you define the function with the instance name `root` instead of `self` which means that `self.entrystring` will generate a NameError.

Then you try to create a Toplevel window as a child to `root`. But `root` is a local variable in the `main()` function and the `menubaroptions()` can't find it.

Now; you are using the decorator `@classmethod` and I'm not one with decorators yet, so I can't say if that affects the problem. But the things I mentioned above will get you part of the way.

Comment: just putting 
trennzeichenentry = tkinter.Entry(... textvariable = root.entrystring, ... ).pack()
 fixed it. I am baffled since i could swear i tried that before but obviously didn´t. Thanks for pointing that out!